# How to apply same settings for Yakuake and Konsole flatpak?

Tags: linux, kde, kubuntu, konsole

I attempted to install Yakuake and Konsole using Flatpak due to issues with the default installation, which produced garbled output and occasional blank lines, resulting in inconsistency. After successfully installing both software packages via Flatpak, they function flawlessly, but there's a slight inconvenience related to settings.

In the native installation, when I modified settings for one application, those changes were automatically applied to the other. However, this seamless synchronization doesn't occur with their Flatpak versions. I now need to manually configure the same settings for both applications, which adds a bit of extra effort.

If anyone has insights or solutions for this situation, I'd greatly appreciate your input.